# Finding Interior Angles of a Triangle Using Angle Between Two Vectors Theorem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Question: Find the interior angles of the triangle with given vertices.
 29. (-4,5) (1,10) (3,1)

My thought process:

First I found the vector of each of the sides by using the head minus tail formula the found the magnitude as shown in the picture below. I was able to get the magnitude easily, but in for the head minus tail you get difference vectors based on which point you assigned as point 1 and 2 and this will eventually lead to different answers  for the angle.

Could someone please explain to me how you know which angle to assign to as one and two?

[image]

Thank you very much.

Comment: If you want the angle at point A, you work with the vectors AB and AC. That is, you work with the vectors starting from that point.

Comment: Why make a simple trigonometry problem difficult by using  irrevelant vector analysis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\vec{AB}=7i-2j, \vec{BC}=-2i+9j,\vec{AC}=5i+7j$,
$\cos B=\hat{AB}.\hat{BC}=\frac{-14-18}{\sqrt{85}\sqrt{53}}=\frac{-32}{\sqrt{85}\sqrt{53}}<0$ So the interior angle $\angle B=\pi-\cos^{-1}\frac{32}{\sqrt{85}\sqrt{53}}$ This also follows from cosine law:
$\cos B= \frac {AB^2+BC^2-AC^2}{2 AB~ BC}=\frac{53+85-74}{2\sqrt{ 53}\sqrt{85}}=\frac{-32}{\sqrt{85}\sqrt{53}}<0$ 
Similarly, $$\cos C= \frac{53}{\sqrt{74}\sqrt{85}}, ~~~\cos A =\frac{21}{\sqrt{53}\sqrt{74}}$$